# Email missing on main computer since receiving mails on iPhone

Tags: email, iphone, email-client

Since I started using an iPhone to receive emails, they are no longer received on my main computer.

My expectation was that the iPhone would receive 'duplicate' messages and all would still be received at main computer but this doesn't happen.

What can I do?

Comment: Are you using POP3? What client are you using on the phone?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like POP3. By default though, the iPhone does not delete messages on the server though.  Which mail client are you using on the iPhone?

**Edit**

Looks like Virgin Media needs explicit settings to download POP mail on more than one device.

http://help.virginmedia.com/system/selfservice.controller?CONFIGURATION=1002&PARTITION_ID=1&TIMEZONE_OFFSET=&USERTYPE=1&VM_CUSTOMER_TYPE=National&CMD=VIEW_ARTICLE&ARTICLE_ID=37916

My suggestion is that you switch to IMAP mode for your email.  Instructions [here](http://help.virginmedia.com/system/selfservice.controller?CONFIGURATION=1002&PARTITION_ID=1&TIMEZONE_OFFSET=&USERTYPE=1&VM_CUSTOMER_TYPE=National&CMD=VIEW_ARTICLE&ARTICLE_ID=3619).

It's quite a read.  I'll quote the short version, but you should read the link for all the details like, "What is IMAP" and the  new IMAP settings for your specific account.

> Enabling IMAP
>
> You can retrieve your Virgin Media Mail messages with a client or device that supports >IMAP, like Microsoft Outlook or Windows Mail.
>   To enable IMAP in your Virgin Media Mail account: Sign in to your
>   Virgin Media Mail account. Click Settings at the top of any Virgin
>   Media Mail page. Click Forwarding and POP/IMAP. Select Enable IMAP.
>   Configure your IMAP client and click Save Changes.

Comment: I have a virgin media account on main computer and iphone sync'd to that.

Comment: iphone on O2 account . . . not sure if that answers the question

Comment: Well, virgin media mail supports IMAP, which is the preferred setting for multiple devices. I also edited my answer.